# Struts page not opening problem

Tags: java, jboss, struts2

I am following the struts 2 framework and using the JBoss server to deploy my application.
I came through this strange behaviour. Please explain it.

i have the following mapping in my struts.xml

```
<action name="Request" class="InboxAction">
<result name="success">/jsp/requestinbox.jsp</result>
<result name="none">/jsp/requestoutbox.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

On my local machine when i run my application. If the result name is "success" the respective `requestinbox.jsp` is invoked and if the result is "none" the `requestoutbox.jsp` is invoked.

But when i deploy it in my JBoss server, `requestinbox.jsp` is displayed when the result is "success". But if the result is "none" I am getting a blank page.

I removed the content from the `requestoutput.jsp` page and replaced with the following line "This is a test" and then I ran my application i was able to see the above line "This is a test".

I tried restarting the JBoss server but no luck. Please tell me the problem and a possible solution.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If I remember correctly, the result "none" always display a blank page (no view). Besides, `javaassist-x.jar` should not include in `your-webapp/WEB-INF/lib` if deploy in JBoss Server. Any error/warning?

Comment: no error no warning... Everything is working fine in my eclipse. But when deployed using jboss... no display..

Comment: The `blank page` means no `html` source at all. You actually want to return `result` "none" (ActionSupport.NONE)? Or just a coincidence the keyword `none` has been used?

Comment: @Ischin : I don't think that if the result name is "none" it will render blank page. I have other actions and results with "none" which are working fine. I figured the solution for the problem and i have posted it below. By the way Thanks for your effort Ischin. I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see the "test" text then your configuration must be right.
I'd say there could be some problems with your values on `valuestack`. Make sure you have provided proper getters and setters for your action and also check the tags in your page to see if values being referred are actually exposed. That's what I would check first.

**Edit for comment**

```
<s:iterator value='listToDiplay'>
    "... whatever you do with values ..."
</s:iterator>
```

You need to expose the `listToDisplay` with a getter method like:

```
public List getListToDisplay(){
    return listToDisplay;
}
```

Comment: value stack??? can u throw some light... Actually i ll be displaying lot of rows say for example 1000 rows... will this be a prob

Comment: @rozar I assume you have a list to display named `listToDisplay`. You need to iterate it in you JSP with struts2 `iterator` tag. In order for iteration to take place you need to expose your `listToDisplay` by a getter method like `getListToDisplay()`. This way iterator tag can iterate your list.

Comment: Thanks Doc...But i was not using the above getter list and still i was able to get the output from my eclipse in my local machine. Why the same i cannot get when i deploy it in jboss

Answer (score 0):

The charset and pageEncoding of the contentType attribute of the page directive which was previously set to ISO-8859-1 has been changed to UTF-8 and the buffer size of the jsp page is increase by the buffer attribute of the page directive like (buffer="6000kb") and the autoFlush attribute of the page directive is set to true like autoFlush="true".

```
<%@ page language="java" buffer="6000kb" autoFlush="true" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```